# Reset broadcast() after each test case while using andCallThrough()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using the code bellow to reset `$broadcast` after each test case, but it seems it `$rootScope.$broadcast.reset();` doesn't function properly, since the test bellow should return 1, but it returns 6.

Seems that the reason for this is `andCallThrough()`, since before I used it without `andCallThrough()` function, but after some refactor it gave me an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined`, so I had to use to prevent that error.

The question is how can i reset the `broadcast` while using `andCallThrough` or is there another more precise approach?

```
beforeEach(function() {
   spyOn($http, 'post');
   spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
});

afterEach(function() {
   $http.post.reset();
   $rootScope.$broadcast.reset();
});

it('should make a POST request to API endpoint', function() {
   $http.post.andCallThrough();
   var response = { id: '123', role: 'employee', email: 'user@email.com', username: 'someUsername' };
   $httpBackend.expectPOST(apiUrl + 'login').respond(response);
   service.login();
   $httpBackend.flush();
   $timeout.flush();
   expect($rootScope.$broadcast.callCount).toBe(1);
   expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, response);
});
```

Comment: If the call to 'expect' testing `callCount` is moved to the first line of the test, what does `callCount` equal then? I wonder if something else in the test is calling `$broadcast`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long investigation of how things work in this situation, finally the tests are passed and the solution is the current:

The issue was not about reseting broadcast() or `reset` method is not called after after each test case while using andCallThrough().
The problem is that the `$rootScope.$broadcast.andCallThrough();`is triggered by other events and the `.callCount()` function returned `6`, which basically means `$broadcast` spy was called 6 times. In my case I am interested only in `AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess` event and make sure it was broadcasted only once.

```
expect($rootScope.$broadcast.callCount).toBe(1);
expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, response);
```

Thus digging the method of `$rootScope.$broadcast.calls` gave my the array of all calls from which the two above expects should be retrieved. Consequently, the solution is:

```
it('should make a POST request to API endpoint', function() {
  $http.post.andCallThrough();
  var response = { id: '123', role: 'employee', email: 'user@email.com', username: 'someUsername' };
  $httpBackend.expectPOST(apiUrl + 'login').respond(response);
  service.login();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  $timeout.flush();

  var loginSuccessTriggerCount = _($rootScope.$broadcast.calls)
    .chain()
    .map(function getFirstArgument(call) {
      return call.args[0];
    })
    .filter(function onlyLoginSuccess(eventName) {
      return eventName === AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess;
    })
    .value().length;

  expect(loginSuccessTriggerCount).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

*A different approach. It is a coffeescript-like pseudo code. Ask in comments if some expressions are not clear. Should say it is not a direct answer on your question. Just a method how to do similar things in a bit another way.*

**Tests with purer state**

Let introduce a variable which will handle a spy for the broadcasting. I use pure spies because `spyOn` may work bad in some cumbersome cases when we deal with method overriding or mixing.

```
rootScope$broadcastSpy = jasmine.createSpy()
```

We need to swap origin implementation with a *stub* which will handle spies and their states. The usual stub definition says it is an entity which doesn't have its own logic. So, we do it in pure way and don't put any logic here. Only a marker (which is represented by a spy).

```
beforeEach module ($provide) ->
  $provide.value '$rootScope',
     $broadcast: rootScope$broadcastSpy

  return
```

Sure, we need to talk jasmine when we need to reset a spy.

```
beforeEach ->
  rootScope$broadcastSpy.reset()
```

Let's define testing scope where we will prepare all needed services and put them in a declarative way to the context (i.e. `this`).

```
instance = (fnAsserts) ->
  inject (loginService, $httpBackend, $timeout, apiUrl, AUTH_EVENTS) ->
    fnAsserts.call
      service: loginService
      apiUrl: apiUrl
      AUTH_EVENTS: AUTH_EVENTS
      '$httpBackend': $httpBackend
      '$timeout': $timeout
```

Let's write the test in blackbox manner. We just setup initial state, then start an action and at the end let's check our marker for changes.

```
it 'should make a POST request to API endpoint', instance ->
  # Given
  response = { id: '123', role: 'employee', email: 'user@email.com', username: 'someUsername' }
  @$httpBackend.expectPOST(@apiUrl + 'login').respond(response)

  # When
  @service.login()

  # Then
  @$httpBackend.flush()
  @$timeout.flush()
  expect(rootScope$broadcastSpy.callCount).toBe(1)
  expect(rootScope$broadcastSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(@AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, response)
```

---

As you see we can chain instance defitions, add more information to them and write each test in purer way because we see the state, the scope, mocks and other needed stuff in single place. We use a closure only for the marker and it garantees that side effects minimzed.

Comment: Thank you @Gulin for your response, since I am not familiar with CoffeeScript this solution seems unclear. Especially, the function `beforeEach module ($provide) -> \n $provide.value '$rootScope', \n $broadcast: rootScope$broadcastSpy \n return` What does `return` returns?

Comment: In coffee every last line is a return. But here I've placed return explicitly to return nothing. `module` implementation uses returned value and I avoid this behaviour by return `undefined` via empty return.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here for the first part of the question

> Reset broadcast()

and this works for me:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast.calls.reset()
```